# iPhone - generic UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, generics

I know how to build and display the XML data in UITableView. And let's say I have an UITableView named: "**DisplayData**" 
I have a same three XML documents. All three have same structure. Ex:

```
Doc1:<data><a>v1</a><a>v1</a></data>
Doc2:<data><a>vx</a><a>vx</a></data>
Doc3:<data><a>ZZZ</a><a>ZZZ</a></data>
```

What I want to do is - that when user selects a row from allready loaded UITableView - a new instance of same code is loaded onto stack of views.

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {
 DisplayData *o = [[DisplayData alloc] init];
 o.rootElementName = @"data";
 o.urlToLoad = self.urlToFolow;
 o.urlToFolow = self.parsedURL;
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:o animated:YES];
 [o release];   
 }
```

So basically I want to load different data and detail data with only one UITableView.

Comment: Hm... Let me clarify the question again: 
I have UITableView which is loaded from button  
DisplayData *o = [[DisplayData alloc] init];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:o animated:YES];
 [o release];
And in this DisplayData I have:

 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {
 DisplayData *o = [[DisplayData alloc] init];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:o animated:YES];
 [o release];   
 }  

So basically Im trying to load same UITableViewController again and again.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep your data in a model object (NSArray ?) and when the user taps on a row you replace the model object with the new data and call `[tableView reloadData]`.

You can also have a look at Apple's Drill Down Table View [example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleDrillDown/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007416-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)...

Comment: Thank you for the example - but this is not what I want to achive. Please read the comment below the question.

Comment: Okay, so instead of following the sample code why can't you just replace your model like I said in my answer?